# Ruby and Minecraft Packets

Tags: python, ruby, hex, packet, minecraft

I need to create a packet and send it to a Minecraft server. The packet needs to packed in a specific way. I managed this in python but ruby seems to be giving me the slip.

Here is the Python code that packs it:

```
def short(data):
    return pack('>h',data)
def shortchar(data):
    return pack('>H',ord(data))
def string16(data):
    chars = ''.join([shortchar(i) for i in data])
    return short(len(data))+chars

packetbytes = '\x02\x33' + string16(name) + string16(host) + '\x00\x00\x63\xdd'
```

How would I do this is Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def string_16(data)
  [data.size].pack('s>') + data.split('').map(&:ord).pack('S>*')
end

packet_bytes = "\x02\x33" + string_16(name) + string_16(host) + "\x00\x00\x63\xdd"
```